# $\ Y = \max\{X, 3\} $ compute $\ E[Y] $

Tags: probability

Let $\ Y = \max\{X, 3\} $ where $\ X \sim B(40,0.1) $

Compute $\ E[Y]  $

My attempt:

$$\ E[Y] = 3\cdot P\{X\le3\} + \sum_{i=4}^{40} i\cdot P\{X=i\} = 3 \left( P\{X=0\}+P\{X=1\}+P\{X=2\}+ P\{X=3\} \right) + \sum_{i=4}^{40} i \cdot P\{X=i\} $$

Then I set again $\ X \sim B(36,0.1) $ and so

$$\ =3 \cdot\left(0.9^{40} + {40 \choose 1}\cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.9^{39} + {40 \choose 2} \cdot 0.1^2 \cdot 0.9^{38} + {40 \choose 3} \cdot 0.1^3 \cdot 0.9 ^{37} \right) + E[X] = \\3 \cdot 0.42313 + E[X] = 1.2693 + (0.1 \cdot 36) =  4.8693 $$
The correct final answer should be 4.318

I guess the problem is with setting new $\ X $ as $\ B(36,0.1) $? but how otherwise could I calculate the expected value of a binomial variable starting from $\ 4 $ to $\ 40 $ without actually calculating every possible outcome * its value?

Comment: There is no reason to set $\ X \sim B(36,0.1)$ while it is $\ X \sim B(40,0.1)$!!!

Comment: Great comment, you are really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to think about it is starting with the E[X] =4. Since max(X,3) =3 for X=0,1,2, we can adjust those values to E[X].

> E[max(X,3)]=E[X] + 3P[X=0] + 2P[X=1] + P[X=2]

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(X=i)$ be the Binomial function, with parameters $40$ and $0.1$.

The probability of r.v. $Y \in \{3, \ldots, 40\}$ is defined as: 
$$P(Y = y) = \begin{cases}
P(X \leq 3) & \text{if}~y = 3 \\
P(X = y) & \text{if}~y > 3 \\
\end{cases} = \\=\begin{cases}
P(X =0)+P(X =1)+P(X =2)+P(X =3) & \text{if}~y = 3 \\
P(X = y) & \text{if}~y > 3 \\
\end{cases}.$$

Therefore,

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=3\left(P(X =0)+P(X =1)+P(X =2)+P(X =3)\right) + \sum_{y=4}^{40} y P(X = y), $$

as you already wrote.

I've checked this with matlab:

```
EY = 0;

for x=0:3
    EY = EY + 3*binopdf(x,40,0.1);
end

for y=4:40
    EY = EY + y*binopdf(y,40,0.1);
end
```

At the end, I get

```
EY = 4.3181
```